# Android 4.1.2 does not show menu button

Tags: android, menu

My app provides a menu which can be reached by clicking the Android menu button.
As Google removed the hardware menu button since 3.0 there is a software emuated button (typically 3 dots) on the screen to access the menu.

A lot of users with a Google Nexus phone complain now that since they updated to 4.1.2 that the menu button does not appear.

Here the code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, 0, Menu.NONE, this.getString(R.string.setting));
        menu.add(0, 1, Menu.NONE, this.getString(R.string.config));
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

What do I have to change to bring the button back also on 4.1.2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem on tablets and now it seems to be generalized to phones also. The only solution is either to add an ActionBar (you'll get then you menu entries in it automatically) or to make the android:targetSdkVersion below 11.

Comment: What I do not understand why the button was there with 4.1. The user started to complain after the update to 4.1.2.

Comment: I think Google want to normalize the behaviors, by the way setting android:targetSdkVersion="8" do the job and brings back the "3 dots" button

Comment: Google wants to get rid of the menu button. From an interface point of view, I can't emphasize enough how good this decision is.

Comment: Ok, I will remove the menu button and think about another solution. Because going to target version 11 makes the app very ugly.

Comment: Yes, basically targeting API level 11 means : "here is my app that was developed for honeycomb, I have not checked that it worked for newer releases so make it run in a compatibility mode".
The good practice is to target the last release of Android. Migrating your app from a menu base UI to the ActionBar will need some work of course, but it will result in a better app. Google did not introduce this change just to annoy the devs.

Comment: **android:targetSdkVersion below 11** made my day !

Comment: Isn't it Ironic that Google banished the options menu to avoid confusion. I think they just wanted to make old devices obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution to this problem is to implement an ActionBar (ActionBarSherlock is a good option if you want to harmonise the look & feel of your app accross Android versions) :

- Android 3.0 & superior : no menu button, corresponding options accessible in the actionbar & overflow menu.
- Earlier versions : use the menu button to access to the corresponding actions.

Comment: I dont want to use the ActionBar. So the only solution would be to the the target version before 3.0 ?

Comment: But is should be noted that it will result in an awful UI. in Android 4.X phones with physical menu buttons but no home button (and again, this layout is where Android is going) it will create a distasteful black band to add the button to the app. Even in phones with virtual button it is very far from a clean implementation.